# socket.io in production with node.js and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

Hello I am setting up my first socket.io chat app for production. I am using netlify to host the front end with react and heroku with JAWSdb for mysql. Here is my back end code with Node.js

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const router = require('./routes/routes');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
app.use('*', cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'cutiewithabooty',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);

const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const options = {
  cors: true,
  origins: ['http://127.0.0.1:4000'],
  'force new connection': true,
};
const io = require('socket.io')(server, options);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  const currentlyConnected = [];
  currentlyConnected.push(socket.id);
  console.log(currentlyConnected);
  console.log('connecting..', socket.id);

  socket.on('chat', (chat) => {
    console.log(chat);
  });

  socket.on('typing', (typing) => {
    io.sockets.emit('typing', typing);
  });

  socket.on('new_message', (data) => {
    io.sockets.emit('new_message', data);
  });

  socket.on('remove', (socket) => {
    console.log('user disconnected!');
  });
});
```

and my front end

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:4000';
var socket = io(ENDPOINT, { forceNew: true });
```

I don't know if i need to change the local host or how to debug but this is what my console says in the browser.

[image: cors error in console]

Comment: Try: `app.use(cors());`

Comment: Also, something non related to the problem:  The `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` and 
`app.use(bodyParser.json());` are deprecated. Instead you can use: `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` and  
`app.use(express.json());`   Reference: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what i had to do was change the Node.js Server to my netlify app which is

```
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const options = {
  cors: true,
  origins: ['https://infallible-pasteur-b0e6fc.netlify.app'],
  'force new connection': true,
};
const io = require('socket.io')(server, options);
```

and on my client side change the endpoint to my heroku app which is

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
const ENDPOINT = 'https://chatroom-express-db.herokuapp.com';
var socket = io(ENDPOINT, {
  forceNew: true,
  origins: 'https://chatroom-express-db.herokuapp.com',
});
```

and volia! it works. Thank you everyone.